# Search UI Autocomplete Input

Tags: javascript, css, ruby-on-rails

How do I create the animation shown on `http://remoteok.io` where examples of possible searches are shown and when the user clicks on the search box they disappear and they can input their own query?

Answer (score 0):

Twitter Typeahead.js can be used to implement similar functionality. See https://blog.twitter.com/2013/twitter-typeaheadjs-you-autocomplete-me & https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/